# How to fix a geolocation API URL to work with specific parameters

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to use the geolocation api to get the latitude and longitude from an address given by the user but it isn't working.

I'm doing the following(in which I'm thinking how to modify the URL to put the key):

```
response = requests.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+request.form.get("address"))

resp_json_payload = response.json()
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> "error_message" : "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account"

This is all the code:

```
import requests

requests.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+request.form.get("address"))

resp_json_payload = response.json()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you have an API key?

Comment: @lusitanica Yes I have one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anywhere after the `?` you can insert your API key `key=yourAPIKey`

```
requests.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=yourAPIKey&address=" + request.form.get("address"))
```

Or

```
requests.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + request.form.get("address") + "&key=yourAPIKey")
```

Comment: The firts option worked, so thank you for helping :D